# What is the purpose of the "Mirror-Thing" over the Mig-29 Cockpit?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, cockpit, fighter, mig-29

I noticed that some Mig-29 Fighter Jets have a little mirror-like-thing over the cockpit. I can't imagine a possible usage from it (If it's really a mirror).

Here's a picture from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan_MiG-29):

[image: Mig-29]

As you can see on the following picture, not every Mig-29 has this thing:

[image]

- What is this "Mirror"-like-thing supposed to do?
- Why can't I find it on every Mig-29?
- When is this thing used? In combat, training etc.?
- How does it help the pilot / trainer in flight?

Comment: I think it's a periscope for the trainer

Comment: It is an actual mirror as you can see more clearly in this image:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Mig-29_on_landing.jpg.
I guess it is used to let the trainer have an unobstructed view.

Comment: Come on, @ratchetfreak, it is indeed a retractable periscope. Put this in an answer already and I upvote you. I hate to leave a question unanswered.

Comment: Asking more then one question  is not advisable but optimal.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Additional details to Marco's selected answer.

On the two-seater version, the instructor seat (aft) is not high enough, contrary to other training aircraft, to see the runway. A forward view mirror replaces the rear view mirror and allows the instructor to see ahead. The runway is projected on a second mirror inside the cockpit, creating a full periscope system:

[image]
<sup>[Photo](http://flickrhivemind.net/flickr_hvmnd.cgi?method=GET&page=4&photo_number=50&tag_mode=all&originput=slovakairforce&search_type=Tags&sorting=Interestingness&photo_type=250&noform=t&search_domain=Tags&sort=Interestingness&textinput=slovakairforce) by [Pavel Vanka](https://www.flickr.com/photos/97026550@N00/albums/72157651485454118). Modified.</sup>

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=3346330365585632&set=a.1721340464751305)</sup>

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://www.migflug.com/jetflights/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MiG-29-periscope.jpg))</sup>

Note how the projected part of the image fits very well into the direct view of the exterior.

An opening is created in the canopy when the top mirror is deployed. From below this is what it looks like (not exactly the same model):

[image]
<sup>[Photo](http://www.b-domke.de/AviationImages/Fulcrum/2161.html) by Burkhard Domk. Modified.</sup>

The bottom mirror unfolds down to instructor eyes height:

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://www.strizhi.ru/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.pl?num=1044026226/40))</sup>

Comment: Very elegant and fairly cheap. Western trainer aircraft have favored "stadium seating" (trainer sits higher than pilot) coupled with a forward-looking CCTV camera, and an instructor familiar enough with the plane that he can land it blind.

Comment: Reminds me of the story about how NASA spent (m|b)illions of dollars to figure out the whole space pen, while Kosmonauts just used a pencil.

Comment: @WayneWerner -- the space-pen story [is a myth](http://www.snopes.com/business/genius/spacepen.asp).

Comment: @Malvolio No source given under the link, and a businessman with an interest in selling his extra-developed "space pens" to NASA.

Comment: @jjack https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1713/415 is relevant. One of the sources cited from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_in_space is http://www.physics.org/facts/apollo-nasa-pen.asp which also states that the USSR started using the same Space Pen at the end of the 1960s.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for the links. It's all still a bit grey, except the NASA page. But even it doesn't give sources other than Fisher's company.

Comment: @WayneWerner - NASA originally used pencils as well. The pen was developed, yes, but not by NASA. It was a product of a pen company. NASA didn't spend anything to develop it but they did buy lots of the pen when it was demonstrated to them to work upside-down (thus should work in zero G)

Answer (score 23):

It's a mirror for a periscope used by the instructor (sitting in the back seat) to see the runway on landing.

As reported [here](http://forums.eagle.ru/showthread.php?t=30371), two-seater versions of MiG-21 and MiG-23 also have the same feature.

In this picture, the periscope is, in fact, clearly visible on the back seat's canopy.

[image: Image of MiG, showing mirror over canopy]
<sup>Image courtesy of [Airvectors.net](http://www.airvectors.net/avmig23_2_5.jpg)</sup>

Comment: The MiG-23's rear seat had really poor visibility, I think they even called it "The Coffin" or something, so the periscope here was a necessity for the instructor to see anything going on ahead